# System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException

Tags: c#, wpf

Доброго вечера всем! Есть такой текстбокс:

```
<TextBox Name="_login" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="180,24,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="232" ToolTip="Логин" TextChanged="_login_TextChanged"/>
```

При открытии формы3 по кнопке из формы1 выдает:

```
+       $exception  {"\"Инициализация \"System.Windows.Controls.TextBox\" вызвала исключение.\": номер строки \"12\" и позиция в строке \"147\"."}  System.Exception {System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException}
```

... я думаю если не этот, то на другой бы указывало.

***Гугл не дал результатов, не подскажите в чем дело?***

p.s. такое выдавало и с "System.Windows.Controls.Buttons"...

Запускаю новое окно так:

```
// Кнопка "Регистрация"
private void registerButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Thread open = new Thread(openReg); 
    open.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    open.Start();
}

        void openReg()
    {
        regWindow regWindow = new regWindow();
        regWindow.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Если не сложно, можете дать совет как окрыть окно в диалоге, чтобы его можно было потом закрыть через к примеру: "regClass.cs". Т.е. прописать что-то типо: regWindow.Close();...

Comment: Операции с UI в WPF (такие как отображение диалога) совершаются в одном потоке. Для начала, стоит попробовать убрать создание `Thread open`.

Comment: @AlexeyM, убрал. Толку 0. Пишет, что запускаемый поток должен быть STA, ибо он не дружит без этого с UI.

Comment: @LiveD: Ну, если вам пишут, что нужен STA-поток, почему вы создаёте контрол в не-STA-потоке? В этом и проблема, очевидно.

---
А, вижу, вы открыли новый STA-поток. Но этого недостаточно, для UI-потока необходимо ещё запустить диспетчер. Но это сложная продвинутая техника, которая мне понадобилась ровно 2 раза в жизни.

Зачем вам вообще нужен отдельный поток? Вы что-то делаете неправильно. Расскажите, какую именно задачу вы решаете.

Comment: Есть класс, допустим: "ClassReg", где происходит обработка данных на форме reg.xaml.cs. Из этого класса, после определенного действия, нужно чтобы в форме login.xaml.cs, подставились поля, а форма reg.xaml.cs закрылась. И пошло выполнение метода из класса "ClassAuth", который связан с формой login.xaml.cs.

Comment: @LiveD: Ну да. А для чего тут отдельный поток?

Comment: @VladD, я просто экспериментировал.

Comment: Есть идеи? Как можно запустить окно из другой формы, а потом закрыть ее через отдельный класс: "haha.cs".

Comment: @LiveD: А в чём проблема? `Window.Show()` в главном потоке. Асинхронность вам может быть ещё понадобится, но не на уровне UI.